# Not rotating tabs around in RubyMine

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

With multi-row tabs, the tabs are always shuffled around so that the tab for the focused file lands on the bottom row. Is there any way to keep the tabs fixed when jumping between files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior depends on the Java Look&Feel and is not controlled by the application. Did you try [RubyMine 4.0 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/RUBYDEV/RubyMine+EAP) with the reworked UI?

Comment: That's unfortunate, but thanks for clarifying. I just installed 4.0, but still does the same thing.